# How does an Indian citizen get a tourist visa for south korea while living in Germany

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, germany, south-korea

I'm a permanent resident in Germany but I'm an Indian citizen. German citizens don't need a visa to visit Korea but Indians do. How and where do I apply for that visa?

Comment: Have you looked into it, asked the embassy ? What have you found so far ?

Answer (score 5):

South Korea has [several representations in Germany](http://deu.mofa.go.kr/worldlanguage/europe/deu/visa/issuance/index.jsp) which receive visa applications from visa nationals resident in Germany.